# I have a question about diagonalization in Godel's context

Tags: logic

I see Godel’s proof (from Penrose) having these main steps.
[1] Enumerate the countable set of {all syntactically correct primitive recursive formulas P(w) of w as a free variable}, by associating each with a godel number say g; so label Pg(. ) the formula of “." that has the gth smallest Gödel number.
[2] Consider the diagonal formula of w that says: `` there is no proof of Pw(w)”; find its Gödel number, say g=148, in the list of Pg formulas in step 1, i.e., we found that P148(w)= "there is no proof of Pw(w)”.
3. See that when P148(w)= "there is no proof of Pw(w) in the system” is evaluated at w=148, the statement is true if the system is consistent.

This is my question: In step 2, suppose instead we consider "Negation of Pw(w) with w as free variable”. Looking at its godel number, say 62, we will have P62(w)=  "Negation of Pw(w)”, and if we evaluate this at w=62 we get
P62(62) = Negation of P62(62), which is nonsense.
But why do we get nonsense in this case, and not in step 2 ? Both the negation and the diagonal are primitive recursive.

Comment: If you want to learn about Gödelian matters, I wouldn't recommend starting with Penrose. For some better suggestions, take a look at my Beginning Math Logic: A Study Guide downloadable at https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl.  In particular, check out pp. 68-69.

Answer (score 2):

*Below, whenever I say "provable" I mean "provable from some appropriate theory" - say, first-order Peano arithmetic.*

This is a subtle point! Basically, the issue is that there is no way to "un-Godelize" a formula. There is no single formula $\varphi(x)$ such that, for each sentence $\psi$ with Godel number $n$, the instance $\varphi(n)$ expresses "$\psi$ is true." Essentially this is because the more complicated a sentence $\psi$ (in terms of [*quantifier rank*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy)), the more complicated it is to assert its truth.

There are a couple follow-up points here:

- First of all, we do indeed have **bounded** truth predicates. For each $n$, there is a $\Sigma_n$ formula $\varphi$ such that for all $\Sigma_n$ sentences $\psi$ with Godel number $k$ we have $\varphi(k)\leftrightarrow\psi$. However, the negation of a $\varphi$-instance is no longer $\Sigma_n$ but rather $\Pi_n$, so we can't implement a Liar-type pheonomenon this way. Similarly, there are $\Pi_n$ truth predicates for $\Pi_n$ formulas, but their anti-instances are $\Sigma_n$ sentences.
- Second, all of this should make you more skeptical of our ability to express "the sentence with Godel number $n$ is provable" in a single way regardless of the complexity of the sentences involved. The point here is that provability of *any* sentence, of arbitrary complexity, is (by Godel's *completeness* theorem) equivalent to the existence of a finite sequence with certain properties. So even if $\psi$ is a $\Sigma_{17}$ sentence, the statement "$\psi$ is provable" is still $\Sigma_1$.

Note that Godel **does not take for granted** that his provability predicate exists; rather, he spends quite a lot of time carefully constructing it!

Comment: Thank you, but I still need help. Penrose (Emperor's new mind, p140), writes "we have numbered all proposition .. which depend on a single variable, so the one we have just written ( ~Exists x [ a Proof with length x proves Pw(w)] ) MUST have been assigned a number. " What is the difference if instead, we use ~Pw(w) and get nonsense ? Are you saying that ~Pw(w) is NOT a member of the list of the propositions that we originally enumerated ?

Answer (score 2):

Noah wrote a good answer, but it seems based on your comment maybe the message got lost in some technical details.

The crucial thing is that when we're asserting a statement is not provable, we're talking *about* the statement (via its Godel number). What you try to do is to assert the statement itself (or really its negation, but same difference). In order to properly maintain the analogy so the diagonalization argument can work, you need to be asserting things *about* the statement, not asserting the statement itself, so you need a "verb" that plays the same role as "is not provable" in the argument for Godel's theorem.

(I haven't read your reference, so I'm not sure how careful it is, but this kind of thing only really becomes clear when you write things down a bit more precisely. If we're meticulous about what's an abbreviation of a formula and what's a Godel number, then it's easier to see how your attempt breaks down.)

The verb you want is "is not true", i.e. the predicate you want to diagonalize is "statement $x$ is not true". The problem is that there's no reason to expect that "is not true" is going to be expressible in the arithmetical language like "is not provable" is... as Noah points out, much of the technical difficulty in proving Godel's theorem is in showing that we can in fact express the latter.

As indicated, it is impossible to express "is not true" in this sense... which is a good thing, since as you note, it would lead to nonsense. This is called [Tarski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem).

Comment: thank you for all the comments. They are helping.